# Can't update data using in Laravel 8. using mcr command

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-10

I'm trying to update the color but am unable to update the color. showing post method is not supported for this route.

What's wrong with the code? Anyone, please give me some suggestions to improve my code. I want to understand what's the problem. So, if anybody can explain in detail then I will really appreciate this thing. I used the command php artisan make:model Color -mcr.

Route:

`Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () { Route::resource('color', 'App\Http\Controllers\ColorController'); });`

Controller:

```
/**

     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $colorupdate = Color::find($request->id);
        $colorupdate->color_name = $request->color_name;
        $colorupdate->slug = Str::slug($request->color_name);
        $colorupdate->save();
        return back()->with('ColorUpdate', "Color Update Successfully");
    }
```

Form:

```html
<form action="{{ route('color.update', $colorview->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Color Name: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $colorview->id }}">
  <div class="col-sm-8 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0">
    <input type="text" name="color_name" class="form-control" value="{{ $colorview->color_name }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-layout-footer mg-t-30 text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Add Color</button> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: please provide the route you have created, and the form

Comment: <form action="{{ route('color.update', $colorview->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf      
<label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Color Name: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $colorview->id }}">
      <div class="col-sm-8 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0">
      <input type="text" name="color_name" class="form-control" value="{{ 
      $colorview->color_name }}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-layout-footer mg-t-30 text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Add Color</button>
    </div>
</form>

Comment: I've attached all the codes. please check it

Comment: Don't post code in the comments. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77222986/edit) and include all of your code there. Thank you. (I've done this for you this time, please make sure you do it yourself next time)

Comment: Instead of asking people to fix your code, first provide context, explain what you are trying to achieve, how you are trying to achieve it, and then how it is failing. If we don't understand what you are trying to de we won't be able to help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since you're using resource, for the UPDATE route, PATCH method is accepted, not POST as already mentioned on the official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)! Include ``@method('PATCH')`` after opening the form tag, include before ``@csrf`` tag!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't make a POST request to an update route is that, usually update routes are of method PUT. Your `Route::resource` creates these routes for you. Read more on the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers

You can check your routes by running `php artisan route:list`.

To be able to "post" to this route you need to include a hidden input of name `_method` and value `PUT`, or use the blade shorthand `@method`

```php
<form action="{{ route('color.update', $colorview->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
```